# Delay in GCS monitoring metrics when deleting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-monitoring

In single-region buckets, a large fraction of the data has been deleted via `gsutil rm`.  When viewing the `Google Cloud Platform` > `Monitoring` > `Metrics Explorer`, with `Resource: GCS Bucket` `Metric: Total bytes` `Group By: bucket_name`, the metrics have not seen a decrease after 6 hours.

The monitoring of requests definitely shows the expected activity at the time the delete was requested, and the files are no longer visible via either `gsutil` or the `GCP` > `Cloud Storage` > `Browser`.

Is there an expected delay in full deletion, or in the monitoring of this metric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The monitoring data is only updated once per day [[doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#storage/storage/total_bytes)].